# Rust transforming a 2D-array to 1D array

Tags: rust, rust-polars

Does someone knows why
`x = df.select(["A"]).unwrap().to_ndarray::<Float64Type>().unwrap()`
is considered as a 2d array while I want it to be 1d array? Is there a function to reshape it to 1d array? Here the shape of `y` is `(100, 1)`.
The type of `x` is a `ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<f64>, Dim<[usize; 2]>>`

Comment: Please tell us what `y` is.

Answer (score 0):

You [Select a list of columns](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/howcani/selecting_data/selecting_data_expressions.html#select-a-list-of-columns), the list having length 1. If the row count is say 100, then your resulting 2D-array has dimension (100, 1).